# Wordpress website with membership subscription, multi vendor product selling and Show content only subscriber users

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, membership

i m new to wordpress. i need to create wordpress website with following functionlity.

1. Membership subscription with role and payment (one time/ recurring).
2. Three type of role (**Admin**,**Provider**,**Enduser**)

**Functionality:**
 1. Both provider and enduser need to register with payment. After registration admin should approve the registration then only they can able to login.
 2. Provider can able to submit their content, video. (Subscribed enduser only able to see this)
 3. Provider can submit their product to the website with payment. Admin should approve the product then only it should be listed in the **shop page**.
 4. Enduser wants to buy any product they can choose and checkout with online payment.
 5. Providers able to view their product sales details in their dashboard.
 6. Providers are able to put their live webinars in the website and track audiance count

Above are the major functionalities. Now my problem is what are all the plugins i needs to use for this functionalities. Because Most of the membership plugins not supporting the multi-vendor product selling. If its support multi-vendor then its not support upload content, video and content protection.

Please any one guide me to choose a plugins for this requirement.

Thanks in advance
Obuliraj Chandran

Comment: Stack overflow is not a free code design and  writing service.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask